# Resume HTTP playback after audio session interruption ends

Tags: iphone, ios, avplayer, http-live-streaming, avaudiosession

I am developing an application that plays HTTP live streaming via AVPlayer. When an my audio session gets interruptued (i.e incoming phone call, launch YouTube application ...) i save the state of my player. When the audio session interruption ends, i try to resume playback. The problem is that the player resumes playback but there is no sound. I figured this out by replaying the last item but i do not think this is the best solution. Could anyone please tell me how to resume playback without having to replay the last item ?

Comment: How about paste your code here? We don't even know how you resume your playback.

Comment: after audio session interruption ends, i invoke the following method :     -(void)onInterruptionEnded{ [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setActive:YES error:nil]; [self.player play]; }

Comment: i am sorry for the non formated code. When audio session interruption ends, i reactivate my audio session and tell my AVPlayer to play (in this case it is a HTTPLive streaming playback).